# Why are we not allowed intercourse with Mahram while children of Adam were allowed to marry them?

Tags: practical-islam, mahram, islamic-events, prophet-adam, sexuality

I want to ask about sexual relations and marriages with mahrams e.g siblings because I read that at time of Hazrat Adam their children had intercourse with each other and so why can't we do it now if that was legal then and they were the prophet's children not any lusty or unislamic people
Plz clear my misunderstanding

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information take the [tour] and refer to the [help].

Comment: Note that each prophet came with his own message and shari'a.

Answer (score 1):

Sacredness of mahram is clear in Qur'aan whereas children of Adam having intercourse with each other is arrived at from deduction and unverified stories, there are even alternate stories that al-hoor al-iyn were sent for them to marry. You can not compare the two.

Even if the story is correct it was because of a need and only applicable to that situation. Even we can eat pork when we are starving and about to die but that does not make pork halal.

Comment: Do you have a reference to your claim of 'Hoor al ayn' being sent for marriage? From the Quran, we understand that they are for the people of Paradise and have never been touched by humans or the jinns.

Comment: Narrated from Ja'far al-Sadiq.

Comment: I understand it is haram obv but there were other choices like Allah could send more people as nothing is impossible for him then why this method of incest?

Comment: @H.m.t.a Only Allah can answer 'Why' He ordered something.